# In a raffle with 100 tickets, 10 people buy 10 tickets each. There are 3 winning tickets which are drawn at random.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that there are three different winners?  My thinking is that this is a hypergeometric set up but I do not know how to set it up.  If $A$, $B$, and $C$ represent the event that a person wins one ticket, $P(A) = \frac{{3 \choose 1}{97 \choose 9}}{{100 \choose 10}}$ is the probability that $A$ wins one ticket.  And $P(D^{c})= 1 - P(A)$ is the probability that $D$ does not win.  My problem is that these events are not independent so I am unsure if this is suppose to be some super long conditional set up.  I feel there is a simpler way to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let person A be the person who won the first ticket.  There are three scenarios in which there are not three different winners:

Scenario 1: Person A wins the 2nd ticket (and may or may not have won the 3rd ticket)

The probability that person A wins the second ticket is $\frac{9}{99}$.

Scenario 2: Person A does not win the 2nd ticket but wins the 3rd ticket.

The probability of this happening is $\frac{90}{99} \cdot \frac{9}{98}$

Scenario 3: Person A does not win the 2nd ticket or the 3rd ticket.  Person B wins the 2nd and 3rd ticket.

The probability of this happening is the probability of person A not winning the 2nd ticket, times the probability of person B winning the 3rd ticket: $\frac{90}{99} \cdot \frac{9}{98}$

The probability of the three distinct winners is therefore one minus the sum of the three aforementioned probabilities:

$$ 1 - \frac{9}{99} - \frac{90}{99} \frac{9}{98} - \frac{90}{99} \frac{9}{98} \approx 74.1\%$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 5):

I think it's much simpler. After the first ticket is selected, to ensure there is a second different winner, we must draw from the remaining 99 tickets one of the 90 not assigned to the first winner; i.e. probability of 90/99. Similarly, for the third, we need one of the 98 not assigned to the first two winners, i.e., 80/98. Hence the probability of three separate winners is

$$\frac{90}{99}\frac{80}{98} \approx 0.742$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  the first ticket drawn cannot go to a duplicate winner (yet).  What is the chance that the second ticket drawn goes to a different person than the first?  Assuming that happens, what is the chance the third ticket goes to somebody different yet?

Comment: Thank you!  I understand now!